# Excel VBA to Copy Every Column in a Sheet to the Next Column to the Right

Tags: vba, excel, batch-processing

I need to accomplish something very simple: copy a complete column to the next column to the right in the same worksheet (I have around 300 of those columns in one sheet of a workbook) meaning that the macros has to copy every odd column in range to next even column so that I end up having a range full of duplicate columns. I understand that I need to use the following formula in part or in full:

```
cells(selection.row, columns.Count).end(xltoleft).offset(,1).select
```

What would be the complete macros though? Searched every available board and found only solutions with custom conditions. Mine should be really simple. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Are you essentially shifting everything to the right? Why not just insert a column to the left?   Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

Comment: @QHarr not shifting (cut and paste), copy pasting to the next column on the right.

Comment: I understand that it should not be complex at all since there are no exclusions. Each column starting with A needs to be copied over to the next one (A to B, C to D, etc.). Not one at a time, batch copy paste to the next to the right for each with a step of 1 (A, C, E... to B, D, F... etc.)

Comment: Do you care that data in B is being overwritten?  i.e. You've said copy A to B, C to D.  Should that data that was in B be preserved / should that also be copied?

Comment: You would write over every column with the data in column 1, If you want to shift all the data, just Insert a column in Column 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try (might need some error handling). Rather than copying entire columns I am using column A to determine the last row of data in the sheet (you can change this) then I am looping the even columns setting them equal to the prior odd columns.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim loopRange As Range

    Set loopRange = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Columns("A:AE")

    Dim lastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    End With

    Dim currentColumn As Long

    With loopRange

        For currentColumn = 2 To .Columns.Count Step 2

            .Range(.Cells(1, currentColumn), .Cells(lastRow, currentColumn)) = .Range(.Cells(1, currentColumn - 1), .Cells(lastRow, currentColumn - 1)).Value

        Next currentColumn

    End With

End Sub
```

If you know the last row:

```
 Option Explicit

    Sub test()

        Dim loopRange As Range

        Set loopRange = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Columns("A:AE")

        Const lastRow As Long = 108

        Dim currentColumn As Long

        With loopRange

            For currentColumn = 2 To .Columns.Count Step 2

                .Range(.Cells(1, currentColumn), .Cells(lastRow, currentColumn)) = .Range(.Cells(1, currentColumn - 1), .Cells(lastRow, currentColumn - 1)).Value

            Next currentColumn

        End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: This solution only moves one column at a time instead of copying it (like I mentioned, I need not to shift but to copy paste keeping the original values in the source columns). I need a batch action for the whole sheet, when in a range, say A1:AE100, each column starting with A (A, C, E, G... etc.) is copied into the next one to the right. The source column values should stay as they are, so the result is A=B, C=D, E=F, etc.

Comment: I’m tired, sorry. you mean copy every odd column in range to next even column so you end up having a range full of duplicate columns?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what is required.

Comment: This worked, thank you! What would be a way to add the last cell to copy until in every column? I understand, that lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row is the line to change. If I know that the max row depth would be 108th for all columns, do I change the line to lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A108").End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Just say lastRow = 108 (bit lazy but) - and comment out   With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    End With

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understood the issue, but please find below a suggestion. The code may be a bit messy since I used a recorded macro:

```
Sub CopyRows()

Range("A1").Activate

While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    ActiveCell.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but this is not working well either, unfortunately. QHarr worded the issue in a very laconic and straightfowrward way: "copy every odd column in range to next even column so you end up having a range full of duplicate columns". Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're hoping to essentially duplicate every column by inserting a copy of each column to the right I think you need the below code.

i.e. this copies columns:

```
A | B | C 
---------
A | B | C 
1 | 2 | 3
```

to

```
A | B | C | D | E | F
---------------------
A | A | B | B | C | C
1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3
```

### VBA

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyAllColsOneToRight()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim currentCopyCol As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'optimise performance by not updating the screen as we move stuff
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastCol = GetLastUsedColumn(ws).Column
    lastRow = GetLastUsedRow(ws).Row

    For currentCopyCol = lastCol To 1 Step -1
        CopyColumnInsertRight ws, lastRow, currentCopyCol
        'CopyColumn ws, lastRow, currentCopyCol, lastRow, currentCopyCol * 2
        'CopyColumn ws, lastRow, currentCopyCol, lastRow, currentCopyCol * 2 - 1
    Next

End Sub

Sub CopyColumnInsertRight(ByRef ws As Worksheet, fromLastRow, fromCol)
    Dim fromRange As Range
    Set fromRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, fromCol), ws.Cells(fromLastRow, fromCol))
    fromRange.Copy
    fromRange.Insert Shift:=XlDirection.xlToRight
End Sub

'Sub CopyColumn(ByRef ws As Worksheet, fromLastRow, fromCol, toLastRow, toCol)
'   Dim fromRange As Range
'   Dim toRange As Range
'   Set fromRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, fromCol), ws.Cells(fromLastRow, fromCol))
'   Set toRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, toCol), ws.Cells(toLastRow, toCol))
'   toRange.Value2 = fromRange.Value2
'End Sub

Function GetLastUsedColumn(ByRef ws As Worksheet) As Range
    Set GetLastUsedColumn = ws.Cells.Find( _
        What:="*" _
        , After:=ws.Cells(1, 1) _
        , LookIn:=XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas _
        , LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlPart _
        , SearchOrder:=XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns _
        , SearchDirection:=XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious _
        , MatchCase:=False _
    )
End Function

Function GetLastUsedRow(ByRef ws As Worksheet) As Range
    Set GetLastUsedRow = ws.Cells.Find( _
        What:="*" _
        , After:=ws.Cells(1, 1) _
        , LookIn:=XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas _
        , LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlPart _
        , SearchOrder:=XlSearchOrder.xlByRows _
        , SearchDirection:=XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious _
        , MatchCase:=False _
    )
End Function
```

Notes on the code:

- We disable screen updating; this avoids refreshing the UI whilst the macro runs, making the process more efficient.
- We get the last populated column so that instead of copying every column on the worksheet we can limit those copied to the ones which make a difference (i.e. much faster for spreadsheets using less that the full number of columns; which will be true of most)
- We get the last populated row so that instead of copying entire columns we only copy populated rows.  We could check for the last used cell per row, but that's likely less efficient since typically the last row will be the same for most columns in range.  Also, when using the insert method this is required to ensure that `xlToRight` doesn't cause cells to be shifted into the wrong columns.
- Our for loop has `Step -1` since if we went from left to right we'd overwrite columns to the right as we copied others (e.g. copying A to B overwrites what's in B, then when we copy B to C we're actually copying the copy).  Instead we work backwards so that we're always copying to blank columns or to columns we've previously copied.
- I've provided a commented out version which only copies values (faster than copying formats), and another version which uses `Insert` to create the new columns.  One may perform better than the other, but I've not tested so far (NB: The copy has to copy twice as many cells as it doesn't keep the originals but creates 2 copies, whilst the insert method keeps the originals and inserts a copy to the right, but has the additional overhead of copying formatting data).